# Why doesn't the derivate fit perfectly with the primitive?

Tags: calculus

Let's consider the following primitive function:
$f(x) = 3x^2 + 5$

$\begin{align}
x = 1 &\Rightarrow f(x) = 8 \\
x = 2 &\Rightarrow f(x) = 17 \\
x = 3 &\Rightarrow f(x) = 32 \\
x = 4 &\Rightarrow f(x) = 53 \text{ etc.}
\end{align}$

The derivative of the function is:
$f'(x) = 6x$.

$\begin{align}
x = 1 &\Rightarrow f'(x) = 6 \\
x = 2 &\Rightarrow f'(x) = 12 \\
x = 3 &\Rightarrow f'(x) = 18 \\
x = 4 &\Rightarrow f'(x) = 24 \text{ etc.}
\end{align}$

Now, let's suppose I'm at $x = 3$, and what to find the value of the primitive function at $x=4$, considering only the value of the primitive at $x = 3$ and the derivative at $x = 3$. Then, we would have:
$f(4) = f(3) + f'(3)$

$53 = 32 + 18 = 50$

$53 \text{ NOT EQUAL to } 50$

So, whatever the value I consider, the estimated value from the derivative always falls behind by 3 (in this case). The essential question is this: Why can't I obtain the exact value of the primitive function at value $x+1$, considering the derivative value for x and the primitive function value at $x$?

Comment: In this case we have $f'(x+1)-f'(x)=6(x+1)-6x=6$ for every $x$ , hence the value of $x$ doesn't play a role. Why did you expect $f(4)-f(3)=f'(3)$ ? Did you interprete the mean value theorem incorrectly ?

Comment: $\frac{f(4)-f(3)}{4-3}$ is NOT $f'(3)$ , it is the slope of the secant with the points $P(3/f(3))$ and $Q(4/f(4))$ , not the slope of the tangent at $x_0=3$ (which is the derivate at $x_0=3$).

Comment: @Peter I believe that I mistyped the equation. Please check now. The derivative function of the primitive function is 6x.